# Why ken yehi ratzon and not Amen?

Tags: tefilla, birchas-kohanim, nusach-ashkenaz, amen

Why is that in the Ashkenaz circles (non Sephardi) by the daily birchat kohanim, the congregation responds “Ken yehi ratzon” rather than the usual response of Amen, after a blessing is recited?

Why do chassidim add “bezchus Avraham Avinu, etc”? When and where did this originate, what’s the connection?